# Flux with dynamic reactjs page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, flux

I have a problem with flux implementation on my app.

Heres the scenario:

We're a site builder plataform, we have pages where we don't know what will be rendering. Its completely dynamic, varying from user to user. 
We have a lot of different components that may ou may not be loaded on the page and each component can have multiple instances.

What we need:

We need a FLUX structure that allows us to load only what we need from store and avoid unnecessary payload.

I have tried using Redux but the problems were:

Firstly we couldn't load all reducers at once but after a few research I built an interface capable of loading reducers on demand. But then I couldn't solve the problem with multiple instances from a component because the store file needs all states pre-refferenced :/

So, here's the question: How can I architect my app to use flux with dynamic pages and multiple instances from a component? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a few (a lot) more research and attempts I'll implement a solution using React + Flux.Dispatcher + Backbone as suggested here:

https://www.toptal.com/front-end/simple-data-flow-in-react-applications-using-flux-and-backbone

===========================

Hope anyone has used that tip above. Worked nice for simple screens, got shit and slowly with complex pages.

Best way is to implement simple flux architecture as described in:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-to-know-flux-the-react-js-architecture
https://blog.risingstack.com/the-react-js-way-flux-architecture-with-immutable-js/

Connect your components with a store via decorator and go for it, works simple majestic.

Hope it's usefull for someone.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is called "lazy loading". So you will just load components and pieces of javascript when they are needed.

Here you can find more information about (you need to generate more bundles of code with webpack):
https://blog.risingstack.com/react-js-best-practices-for-2016/

I will need this in a project in few months, but right now in our MVP we just need to make things run :)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, @tulio-faria. 
We already use lazy loading on our app, we have everything on demand though webpack chunks.

What we want is a place to store all our states and manage them via actions (also centralized). Redux was great till these problems poured out :/